# Usar un case con datos de una tabla y que los resultados de ese case los guarde en una tabla

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Tengo 1 tabla llamada 'CFACTURACOMISION' la cual tiene las columnas.
*CLFILIAL, CLCLIENTE, CLASESOR, FOFACTURA, FECHAFACTURA, MNFACTURA, MNDESCUENTO MNIVA, MNTOTAL, FEVENCIMIENTO, CONDICIONESDEPAGO, PROMVENTA.*

**El principal objetivo de esta tabla es capturar las facturas para después verificar que todos los pagos que se realizaron y posteriormente darle una comisión al vendedor que realizó esa venta.**

Primeramente hago la suma de todos los pagos realizados a una factura, obteniendo los datos de la tabla 'FACTURA_PAGOS'.

```
Select FACTURA_PAGOS.FOFACTURA, sum(factura_pagos.imp_cobro) from factura_pagos, CFACTURACOMISION where CFACTURACOMISION.FOFACTURA = FACTURA_PAGOS.FOFACTURA AND  FACTURA_PAGOS.FECHA_DEP<= CFACTURACOMISION.FEVENCIMIENTO group by FACTURA_PAGOS.FOFACTURA;
```

Después de eso tendría que hacer un IF que verifique si todos los pagos son=MNFACTURA en caso de que la factura estuviera pagada que corriera este case que tengo, actualmente lo tengo con  valores predeterminados, entonces necesito que tome los datos de la tabla.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
MNDESCUENTO NUMBER:=0;
COMISION NUMBER:=0;
CONDICIONESDEPAGO NUMBER:=0;
PROMVENTA NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
CONDICIONESDEPAGO:=4;
PROMVENTA:=30000;
MNDESCUENTO:=12;
CASE
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '0' AND '30000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '0' AND '4' AND  MNDESCUENTO>0 AND MNDESCUENTO<=12 THEN COMISION:=.05;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '0' AND '30000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '5' AND '35' AND MNDESCUENTO>0 AND MNDESCUENTO<=12 THEN COMISION:=.03;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '30000' AND '100000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '0' AND '35' AND MNDESCUENTO>0 AND MNDESCUENTO<=12 THEN COMISION:=.03;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '0' AND '100000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '0' AND '35' AND MNDESCUENTO>12 AND MNDESCUENTO<=13 THEN COMISION:=.03;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '0' AND '1000000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '0' AND '35' AND MNDESCUENTO>13 AND MNDESCUENTO<=17.5 THEN COMISION:=.02;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '30001' AND '100000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '0' AND '35' AND MNDESCUENTO>17.5 AND MNDESCUENTO <=20 THEN COMISION:=.01;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '100001' AND '10000000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '0' AND '36' AND MNDESCUENTO>17.5 AND MNDESCUENTO <=20 THEN COMISION:=.01;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '0' AND '10000000' AND  CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '36' AND '45' AND MNDESCUENTO>=1 AND MNDESCUENTO <=7 THEN COMISION:=.03;
WHEN PROMVENTA BETWEEN '0' AND '10000000' AND CONDICIONESDEPAGO BETWEEN '46' AND '60' THEN COMISION:=.03;
END CASE;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ' COMISIÓN DEL ' ||COMISION ||'%');
END;
```

No se si puedan ayudarme, actualmente me regresa la comisión mediante una DBMS pero sin validar los pagos.

Answer (score 1):

Carlos, pero no veo que estés sumando los valores, solo los estas pasando por un case.
Podrías hacer lo siguiente si quieres el resultado de la comisión.

1. Poner la sumatoria SUM(case...) y agrupar las otras variables.
2. Cargar tu select en un cursor, recorrer el cursor y en el recorrido ir sumando con el case y cargando el valor en un parámetro.

No es muy clara tu consulta, pero creo que lo último es lo que estas buscando.

```
CURSOR C_MICURSOR IS
SELECT * FROM MITABLA
V_COMISION := 0;

BEGIN 
    FOR C IN C_MICURSOR 
    LOOP
    /* Hacer lo que se necesite aquí */
    V_COMISION := V_COMISION + (Nuevos valores)
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error en la transaccion:'||SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```